# C# lambda: Why isn't this line of code working?

Tags: c#, lambda

This line won't work:

```
public List<T> GetTypes(Type type) => new List<T>().AddRange(
                                        elements.ForEach(x => x.GetType() == type)
                                      );
```

Error   CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: elements.ForEach(x => x.GetType() == type) doesnt return a list, did you mean where?

Comment: `AddRange` doesn’t return a value. Did you mean `elements.Where(x => x.GetType() == type).ToList()`?

Comment: Use the `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>) constructor instead of the parameterless constructor. Or use a LINQ query followed by a `ToList()`

Comment: @Emily, check out if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42023428/1016343) solution works for you...

Answer (score 4):

Because `List.AddRange` returns void, and voids can't be used as return values.

This should do the trick though:

```
new List<T>(elements.Where(x => x.GetType() == type))
```

Or:

```
elements.Where(x => x.GetType() == type).ToList()
```

And if you can express `type` as the actual type, like `string`, you could even use this:

```
elements.OfType<string>().ToList()
```

Comment: The solution in this answer is totally correct, but the mentioned error (Error CS0201) is caused by the inner `ForEach` and its lambda expression and not by the `AddRange` method.

Comment: Okay, it could have been both, since both would give that exception, but thanks for pointing that out @lukegv

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to filter a generic list by type. 
The code snippet you provided does not work, because of three reasons:

1. `.AddRange(...)` does not return a list but `void`, hence it cannot be used in fluent syntax. You could fix that via 
    `... => { var lst = new List<T>(); lst.AddRange(elements.Where(x => x.GetType() == type)); return lst; }`
    if lambda declarations would allow `var`, but unfortunately they don't allow it. So you need to add another parameter passing a `List<T>`.
2. There is an issue with the way the snippet is using generics: You can't just declare a `List<T>` without providing a generic parameter `T`, either on class level, or on function level.
3. `.ForEach(...)` is not the right method here, you need a `.Where(...)` method.

Taking into account the topics above, you can solve it as follows (`static` is required because extension methods must be static):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extensions
{
    // Extension method: filters elements by type
    public static List<T> GetTypes<T>(this List<T> elements, Type type)
                => elements.Where(x => x.GetType() == type).ToList();
}

public class Program
{
    // demonstrates how it is working
    public static void Main()
    {
        var elements = new List<object> {
            (int)3, (string)"Hello", (int)5, (string)"World"
        };
        var filteredList = elements.GetTypes(typeof(System.String));
        foreach (var x in filteredList) Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
    }
}
```

It filters the strings from the `elements` list and returns them, i.e. the output is:

> Hello 
>   World

**Extension methods** have the benefit that you only need to specify one of the 2 parameters (as demonstrated in the `Main` method). You can also use it with 2 parameters, or you could declare it as a normal function as well - but here I think there is an advantage to use it.

**[Try it with .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZX53Zg)**